# Sinon unit test timeout exceeded

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I want to implement the unit test for the following method in Simon, Mocha and Chai:

```
function createApp(req, res) {
    return maintenanceResponse(res);
}

function maintenanceResponse(res) {
    res.status(503).json({'status': 'scheduled maintenance, please try again later'}).end();
}
```

Here is what I implemented:

```
it('Test Create App', function(done) {
        const req = {};
        const res = {
            // status: sinon.stub().returns({json: sinon.stub().returns({end: sinon.stub()})}),
            status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
            json: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
            end: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        };

        indexController.createApp(req, res);

        expect(res.status.calledOnceWith(503)).to.be.true;
        expect(res.end.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
```

But I got a timeout error:

```
 1 failing

  1) Test Create App:
     Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded
      at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:158:19)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved!

I forgot to add

```
done();
```

in the test file!